# Problems with django template and views

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views, django-urls

Hello everyone thanks in advance on the aid, I'm new in programming in general.
I would like to create a link in the voice actor (in Film.html) and using the ID to open a new page (Attore.html) where to load only the data associated with that ID but it doesn't do that since it loads them all but I don't understand where it's the error. I don't also know why not charge the CSS in Attore.html, while in Film.html there are no problems and it is strange since it is located on Base.html.

Here is the code a little simplified.

**models.py :**

```
from django.db import models

class Attore( models.Model ):
    nome = models.CharField( max_length=30 )
    cognome = models.CharField( max_length=30 )
    foto = models.CharField( max_length=100 )
    data_inserimento = models.DateField( null=True, verbose_name="data d'inserimento" )
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.nome + " " + self.cognome + " " + self.foto
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Attori"

class Film( models.Model ):
    titolo = models.CharField( max_length=39 )
    trama = models.CharField( max_length=1000 )
    locandina = models.CharField( max_length=100 )
    copertina = models.CharField( max_length=100 )
    data_inserimento = models.DateField( null=True, verbose_name="data d'inserimento" )
    attori = models.ManyToManyField( Attore )
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.titolo + " " + self.trama + " " + self.locandina + " " + self.copertina
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Film"
```

**views.py :**

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response, get_object_or_404
from django.template import RequestContext
from models import *

def film(request):
    film = Film.objects.order_by("titolo")
    return render_to_response('Film.html', { 'film': film, })

def film_attore(request, id):
    get_attore_id = get_object_or_404( Attore, pk=id )
    return render_to_response('Attore.html', { 'film': Film.objects.filter( attori=get_attore_id ), 'attor': get_attore_id })
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *

urlpatterns = patterns('',    
    (r'^Film$', 'Database.views.film'),
    (r'^Attore/(\d+)/$', 'Database.views.film_attore'),
)
```

***Template:***

**Base.html :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>{% block titolo %}Titolo{% endblock %}</title>
  <link href="../static/css/Default.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
  {% block contenuto %}Contenuto{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

**Film.html :**

```
{% extends "Base.html" %}

{% block titolo %}Film{% endblock %}

{% block contenuto %}
  {% for dato in film %}
    {% for attore in dato.attori.all %}
      <a href="/Database/Attore/{{ attore.id }}">{{ attore.nome }} {{ attore.cognome }}</a>
    {% endfor %}
  {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

**Attore.html :**

```
{% extends "Base.html" %}

{% block titolo %}Attore{% endblock %}

{% block contenuto %}
  {% for dato in film %}
    {% for attore in dato.attori.all %}
      <h2>{{ attore.nome }} {{ attore.cognome }}</h2>
    {% endfor %}
  {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing is you should put an absolute path to your css, not a relative one, that's why is not loading.

Then, to me it looks like the code is doing exactly what it's told. In the `film_attore` view you pass the list of movies and the actor to the template but in the template you don't use the `attori` variable and instead iterate over all movies for this actor then lookup and print the list of all actors in each movie.

Comment: Could you help me by editing the code I posted? please, thank you.

Comment: I want to display only the attore that i call by id, so I have to use the attori variable? Thank.

Comment: in your view you pass the actor using the `attor` variable so use `{{attor.nome}}` etc. to display the data

Comment: ok i'm totaly stupid

{% extends "Base.html" %}

{% block titolo %}Attore{% endblock %}

{% block contenuto %}
      <h2>{{ attore.nome }} {{ attore.cognome }}</h2>
{% endblock %}